# What is the meaning of the phrase `to be dangerous`?

Tags: sentence-meaning

When I studied 'ruby' by an e-book, I couldn't understand this sentence:

> Learn Enough Command Line to be Dangerous.

What is the meaning of the phrase `to be dangerous` in the picture attached below?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: The first example  that came to me was my aunt who was head nurse in a neonatal unit -- and brilliant at that. When my friend had a brain tumour, she had enough knowledge to be dangerous. He trusted her because she was a great  nurse, but that was not her area of expertise and she was making suggestions that went against what the doctor had said. She knew enough about medicine *to be dangerous*. In your examples, it probably means : to have a basic understanding.

Comment: @WRX why haven't you posted this brilliant comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Enough to be dangerous" means that you know enough to make big (potentially dangerous) decisions or actions, but don't have enough experience to know when such activity is advised and when it should be avoided.

See also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158755/is-there-a-way-to-express-knowing-just-enough-to-be-dangerous-succintly).

Answer (score 1):

This expression has two parts, first one is:

> **to be** - this verb used when we want to describe some features, qualities, attributes (to be beautiful, to be smart, to be on time...). In terms of this sentence, used for description the quality as 'dangerous'.

Elaboration of meaning ['to be'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be) by Oxford dictionary

the second part is:

> the word **'dangerous'** - means you should avoid using some 'command line'. Command line probably has some features that can be defined as dangerous. But what exactly dangerous you haven't asked yet and moreover, it isn't clear.

Elaboration of meaning ['dangerous'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dangerous) by Oxford dictionary

Usage of the verb ['to be'](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verb-be) by British Council

> Put it together *(to be dangerous)* - Command Line **has features that could be distinguished as unwanted *(you should avoid using)***. As it mentioned above, what exactly dangerous it isn't clear from the context